# Language to describe that a multivariate function is convex with respect to only certain variables

Tags: notation, convex-analysis, article-writing

Consider the following function:

$$f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2$$

I am writing a paper with such a function in which I stated "$f$ is convex only in variables $x$ and $y$". By this I mean that for any constant $a$, $f(x, y, a)$ is a convex function of $x$ and $y$. I figured my meaning would be clear from context, but my advisor told me that he thinks that this language is potentially ambiguous and asked me to consult the literature to make sure my verbiage is consistent with that which other mathematicians and scientists use for such functions.

The problem is that wherever I have looked I can only find the definition for a function being convex as a whole. I have found no reference that gives any kind of standard notation/name for the situation I described. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Perhaps the answer is right in the title of my question. I could say "$f$ is convex with respect to only $x$ and $y$". But this begs the same: is this standard usage of the language/is the meaning clear and unambiguous?

Comment: If you have to ask....

Comment: @copper.hat yeah, good point. The best course is probably to simply rewrite the sentence in question to avoid the issue altogether. But I am still curious....

Comment: It is a gray area, best avoided for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I would write: "For each value of $a$, the function $f(\cdot, \cdot, a)$ is convex"
or
(very similarly)
"For each value of $a$, the function $(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y,a)$ is convex".